# is_float() in Php not working in loop

Tags: php

```
$number = 5;
for ($i=$number;$i>.9;$i=($i/2)){
    if (is_float($i))
    {
      echo $i.' is float <br>';
      $i=$i-0.5;
    }
    else
    {
      echo $i.' is not float <br>';
    }
}
```

Result::

5 is not float

2.5 is float

1 is float

Why 1 is float?? Whats wrong???

Comment: 1) You initialize `$number` with the integer 5. 2) You never again change `$number` in your code 3) You always check if `5` (`$number`) is a float ...

Comment: I have corrected it now another problem raised. ...

Answer (score 2):

Replace `if (is_float($number))`
 with `if (is_float($i))`

Answer (score 1):

Replace `$i=$i-0.5;`
  with `$i=intval($i);`

Comment: solved. Thanks to @Rizier123 now the results shows perfect.